# startup failed due to plugin com.android.application

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

Since i updated the android studio i am getting error

> ERROR: startup failed: build file
>   'C:\Users\Personal\AndroidStudioProjects\VoiceAssistant\app\build.gradle':
>   1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 3.    �� a p p l y   p l u g
>   i n :   ' c o m . a n d r o i d . a p p l i c a t i o n ' 
>        ^
>
> 1 error

my gradle file

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.personal.voiceassistant"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate cache and restart in Android Studio.

Click on File -> Invalidate Cache and Select Invalidate and Restart.